# Zend Framework on iis7

Tags: zend-framework, iis, web-config, url-rewriting

Recently setup a site on my windows server running Zend Framework and only the index.php page shows correctly. All other internal pages look like they are being redirected to index.php with the URL being rewritten as the correct page URL. Really strange and can't seem to figure out if it's the server configuration or the retire rules in web.config.  Any advice would be most appreciated. 
Thanks
Kam

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 2008 Server with IIS 7 I have the following web.config file for my ZF apps in the root of the server ("C:\intepub\wwwroot") which allows me to run the application the same way as on Linux servers.

Hope this helps you and others to get started on Windows with IIS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Get rid of the world wide web" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Ignore files on the filesystem" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Point to the site entry gate" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```